# Popular select com resultado mais um elemento nulo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho um método que invoca a view da seguinte maneira:

```
return view('auth.register',[
    'teachers' => $this->user->mentors()->lists('name','id'),
]);
```

E na view, o `select` usando `{{ Form::select() }}` ocorre perfeitamente. O método mentors retorna os professores em ordem alfabética e pega apenas o `name` e a `id` com o `list`, até aí é óbvio.

Mas eu gostaria de acrescentar um `option` no início do `collection` "Escolha um professor". Fiz dessa maneira:

```
collect(['' => 'Escolha um professor'])->merge($this->user->mentors()->lists('name','id'));
```

Mas fazendo isso, o valor do `id` é substituído pelo `index`, como se fosse um array.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar o primeiro campo nulo da seguinte forma:

```
{{ Form::select('name',['' => 'Selecione']+$teachers,'') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente adicionar o atribute `placeholder` no seu campo html, por exemplo:

```
{!! Form::select('teacher', $teachers, null, ['placeholder' => 'Escolha um professor']) !!}
```

Ou, se a opção `escolha um professor` possuir um valor diferente do padrão, null por exemplo, você pode continuar adicionando um novo item no início da lista, dessa forma:

```
$teachers = array_replace(
    [null => 'Escolha um professor'],
    $this->user->mentors()->lists('name','id')->toArray()
);
```

Também não vejo problema em disponibilizar explicitamente uma opção desabilitada para o select, por exemplo:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um professor</option>
    <option value="Professor Eduardo">Eduardo</option>
    ...
</select>
```